# Array into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, insert

I've a few examples but nothing that I can grasp.  I have the below code, the echos work but the insert does not.  I believe I'm suppose to explode these?  Not sure but maybe someone can give me a hint with my own example.

```
$con=mysqli_connect(localhost,"username","password","db");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$deletetable = $con->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE twitch_streams');
$deletetable->execute();
$deletetable->close();

$result = $con->prepare("SELECT field_value
FROM xf_user_field_value
WHERE field_id = 'twitch'
AND field_value != ''");

$result->bind_result($twitchfield);

while($result->fetch())
{
printf("%s\n", $twitchfield);
$username[] = $twitchfield;
$data =    json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/l   ist.json?channel=' . $username[0]));
$viewer[] = $data[0]->channel_count;


$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert = bind_param('si', $twitchuser, $viewercount);

$twitchuser = $username[0];
$viewercount = $viewer[0];

$insert->execute();

echo $twitchuser;
echo $viewercount;
$insert->close();
  }

$result->close();$deletetable = $con->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE twitch_streams');
$deletetable->execute();
$deletetable->close();

$result = $con->prepare("SELECT field_value
FROM xf_user_field_value
WHERE field_id = twitch
AND field_value != ''");

$result->bind_result($twitchfield);

while($result->fetch())
  {
   printf("%s\n", $twitchfield);
   $username[] = $twitchfield;
   $data =    json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/l   ist.json?      channel=' . $username[0]));
$viewer[] = $data[0]->channel_count;


$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert = bind_param('si', $twitchuser, $viewercount);

$twitchuser = $username[0];
$viewercount = $viewer[0];

$insert->execute();

echo $twitchuser;
echo $viewercount;
$insert->close();
  }

$result->close();
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Guys, PLEASE USE PLACEHOLDERS if you can.

Comment: try echoing your query

Comment: I edited my main post to show my whole code.  I run a query to get data, take that data and run it through the JSON API, and then I'm trying to store results in another table.  *Edit, I think I see what I needed.  Thanks John!

Comment: *Edited thanks John,  I think I figured it out.  Would the prepared statement take place of the escape?  Or should I still escape even when preparing?

Comment: Did you just put this together for us or is this your real code?
Because you are missing quotes around "localhost", too.
Escaping is done by the mysqli engine IF you work with correct placeholders. You do not need to do it.

Comment: Ok updated with me trying to learn the prepared statements take on it.  But so far no luck getting it to run.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing quotes around your string values:

```
"INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES ($username[0], $viewer[0])"
```

should be

```
"INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES ('$username[0]', '$viewer[0]')"
```

You would spot this error easily if you add error handling to your code. Look into using [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO twitch_streams (twitchuser, viewercount)
VALUES ('$username[0]', '$viewer[0]')");
if (!result) {
    // This should be done better than this
    echo mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
```

Since I can't tell from your code what the source of `$data[0]->channel_count` is I will also mention that you should at least escape your insert variables with [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string). Even better, use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).